# Como insertar la hora y fecha actual en real_scape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

estoy intentando insertar una fecha y hora actual a una base de datos Mysql con php, todos los datos estoy insertandolos por ejemplo el nombre, de esta manera:

```
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['nombre'])),
```

Pero quiero que en este caso sea solo la fecha y hora actual al momento de llenar el formulario, he intentado varias cosas pero no me ha funcionado, este campo será un hidden ya que solo quiero que sea visible para mi en la DB.

Muchas Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no agregas una columna en la tabla cuyo valor por defecto sea la fecha/hora actual? Así cuando se inserte un registro esa columna se llenará sola sin necesidad de hacerlo tú.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo insertes enviando la fecha desde una variable, hazlo directamente en la consulta, de la siguiente manera :

```html
INSERT INTO historico (Id_Historico,Id_Bien,Activo,SubActivo,Fecha_Resguardo,Fecha_Actualizacion,Fecha_Asignacion,Observaciones)
VALUES (NULL,$Id_Bien,$Activo,$SubActivo,now(),now(),now(),'$Observaciones')";
```

Esa simple instrucción now() inserta la fecha y hora del sistema del momento en que se efectúa la operación de inserción.

Saludos